# Prune tree branches where ending nodes meet some criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `TreeNode` class as follows:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public enum NodeType { Root,Element, Category}
    public TreeNode()
    {
        Children = new List<TreeNode>();
    }
    public List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public NodeType Type { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a `BuildTree` method that populates the tree structure setting the node Name and type for each node (e.g. The first node will be set to Root Type, and child nodes could be either Element or Category types).

I'm looking for an efficient way (perhaps using LINQ) to prune tree branches where the ending node type is not of type Category. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Here a visual example:

**Before**:

```
Root
|
|_ NodeA (Element)
|_ Node B (Element)
|  |_ Node B.1 (Category)
|_ Node C (Element)
|  |_ Node C.1 (Element)
|    |_Node C.1.1 (Category)
|_ Node D (Element)
   |_Node D.1 (Element)
```

**After**:

```
Root
|
|_ Node B (Element)
|  |_ Node B.1 (Category)
|_ Node C (Element)
   |_ Node C.1 (Element)
     |_Node C.1.1 (Category)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many levels do you want to prune from the leaf node?

Comment: I updated the question with a visual representation of what I want. Basically prune the whole branch from the Root if it doesn't end in Category

Comment: +1 for an interesting/fun problem...No need to specify LINQ,though, people should give you answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to describe how to do a depth first aggregation of a tree:

```
//seed: leafNode -> accumulate
//func: interiorNode, children accumulates -> accumulate
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TAccumulate>(
    this TreeNode root,
    Func<TreeNode, TAccumulate> seed,
    Func<TreeNode, List<TAccumulate>, TAccumulate> func)
{
    if (root.Children == null || !root.Children.Any())
        return seed(root);
    return func(root, children.Select(child => child.Aggregate(seed, func)).ToList());
}
```

Then we can use that to make a modification such as the one you requested:

```
tree.Aggregate(
    leaf => new
    {
        Keep = leaf.NodeType == TreeNode.NodeType.Category,
        Node = leaf
    },
    (node, children) =>
    {
        var removal = new HashSet<TreeNode>(
            children.Where(child => !child.Keep).Select(child => child.Node));
        node.Children.RemoveAll(removal.Contains);
        return new
        {
           Keep = children.Any(child => child.Keep),
           Node = node
        };
    });
```

This gives you a concise, declarative way to describe what transform you want applied to your tree without getting into the details of the traversal in the description of the transform.

Comment: That will take me the whole weekend at least to understand. It worked! Thanks @Timothy Shields. Beauty, hats off

Comment: @AdolfoPerez Also, please upvote if the answer worked for you.

Comment: I would replace the `foreach` with either `node.Children = children.Where(child => child.Keep).ToList()`, if you want to re-create the list, or `node.Children.RemoveAll(children.Where(child => !child.Keep))` if you don't.

Comment: @Servy `List<T>.RemoveAll` takes a `Predicate<T>`, not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Right, you'd need: `var badChildren = new HashSet<TreeNode>(children.Where(child => !child.Keep)); node.Children.RemoveAll(child => badChildren.Contains(child));`

Comment: @Servy Agreed - that's certainly a significant performance improvement if some nodes have many children, but I figured that omitting that kind of optimization would make the answer clearer.  I'll update the answer for you though.

Comment: The only part I don't like is that this code requires Children to be a List. Also, there's a problem with the code: the `Aggregate` method doesn't compile. In the part where it says `children.Select`, `children` doesn't exist. I think it should be `root.Children` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that complex; you just need a recursive traversal of the tree.  The base case is that the node itself is a category.  Then just call the function on each of the children and keep those that have a category among their children.

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes all child nodes that do not have at least one Category as a child.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="node">The node to alter the children of.</param>
/// <returns>True if there is at least one Category in this subtree</returns>
public static bool RemoveEmptyElements(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Type == TreeNode.NodeType.Category)
        return true;
    node.Children = node.Children.Where(child => RemoveEmptyElements(child))
            .ToList();
    return node.Children.Any();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine too @Servy. Unfortunately I already marked the answer but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use post-order to traverse a tree. When you go back to 2nd level of the tree without finding a category type leaf. Traverse again from this node to delete all leaves rooted from it.